# ¿Cómo puedo poner un botón delante de otro en Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

como digo en el titular, quiero poner un imagebutton delante de un button mas grande. Pero el button tapa al imagebutton y no encuentro la variable para cambiarlo.

Estoy usando Constrainlayout.

Este es el código de los dos botones.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#A39D35"
    android:keepScreenOn="false"
    android:rotationY="0"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="581dp" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, conviene que edites la pregunta incluyendo el código que has escrito para llegar a este resultado, de acuerdo con la [guía de cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un RelativeLayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/img_size_height"
                        android:background="@color/grey_10"
                        android:foreground="@color/overlay_dark_30"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/imagen" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_logo_size_width"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_logo_size_height"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/button"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Button" />

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).